# URL passed from Apex Controller becomes null in JS controller

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am for some reason having a problem with a URL being returned from Apex controller to Javascript when clicked a button. In Apex controller, the getSenderViewUrl method does not return null, it returns a real URL (https://appdemo.docusign.com/auth-from-console?code=...), but in the Javascript, it is always null, even though it is not returned null from the Apex Controller. Could anyone explain why is that? I added comments where you can see what is null and what is not. Thanks a lot.

LWC:

```
<div>

    <lightning-button label="Send envelope with documents" title="Send envelope with documents" onclick={handleClick}>Test button</lightning-button>

</div>
```

Apex Javascript:

```
    import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import sendEnvelope from '@salesforce/apex/envelopeSendingController.sendEnvelope';
import getSenderViewUrl from '@salesforce/apex/envelopeSendingController.getSenderViewUrl';
export default class SendEnvelopeWithDocuments extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;   
 
    handleClick() {


        sendEnvelope({

         mySourceId: this.recordId

        })

    .then(getSenderViewUrl({ // calling the getSenderViewUrl method
        mySourceId: this.recordId
    }))
    .then((senderViewUrl) => {
        window.location.href = senderViewUrl; // senderViewUrl is null here 
    })
    .catch((error) => {

        console.log('Error:');

        console.log(error);

    });

}
}
```

Apex Controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
@Future(callout=true)
public static void sendEnvelope(Id mySourceId) {
       system.debug(mySourceId);
        Orders__c myOrder = [Select Id,DS_tempID__c, DS_envID__c, DS_signName__c,DS_signEmail__c From Orders__c where Id = :mySourceId]; 
        
        // Create an empty envelope with Opportunity Id as the source Id
        dfsle.Envelope myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(new dfsle.Entity(mySourceId));

        //use the Recipient.fromSource method to create the Recipient
        dfsle.Recipient myRecipient = dfsle.Recipient.newEmbeddedSigner(
                    myOrder.DS_signName__c, // Recipient name
                    myOrder.DS_signEmail__c, // Recipient email
                    myOrder.Id); //This is the clientUserId in the API call

    myRecipient.withRole(new dfsle.Recipient.Role('Signer 1',1));
        
        //add Recipient to the Envelope
        myEnvelope = myEnvelope.withRecipients(new List<dfsle.Recipient> { myRecipient }); 
        
                
        //This pulls all the documents from the Opportunity Object and adds them to documents list
        List<dfsle.Document> documents = dfsle.DocumentService.getLinkedDocuments
                (
                ContentVersion.getSObjectType(),
                new Set<Id>{myOrder.Id},
                false
                );
                
        //add document to the Envelope
        myEnvelope = myEnvelope.withDocuments(documents); 
        
        // Send the envelope. 
        myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(
            myEnvelope, // The envelope to send
            false); // Send now parameter not actually part of this method.
      System.debug('Sent ENvelope');
      System.Debug(myEnvelope.Id);
        
        myOrder.DS_envID__c = String.valueOf(myEnvelope.docuSignId);
        
        update myOrder;     
}

@AuraEnabled
public static String getSenderViewUrl(Id mySourceId) {
   // String url = Apexpages.currentPage().getUrl();
    String url = 'http://www.google.com';
    System.debug('my source id: ' + mySourceId);
    
    Orders__c myOrder = [Select Id,DS_tempID__c, DS_envID__c, DS_signName__c,DS_signEmail__c From Orders__c where Id = :mySourceId];
    Url mySendingUrl = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getSenderViewUrl(
    dfsle.UUID.parse(myOrder.DS_envID__c), 
    new URL(url));

    System.debug('sending url: ' + mySendingUrl);
    System.debug('external form: ' + mySendingUrl.toExternalForm()); // this prints out a real URL
    return mySendingUrl.toExternalForm();
}
```

Comment: if you are calling the method like this: `getSenderViewUrl({ // calling the getSenderViewUrl method`... it'll likely break, because you are including a comment inside a JSON object, which is not allowed. Or was this for illustration purposes only?

Comment: Only for illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured it out.

Incorrect part:

```
.then(getSenderViewUrl({ // calling the getSenderViewUrl method
    mySourceId: this.recordId
}))
```

Corrected:

```
.then(() => (getSenderViewUrl({
    mySourceId: this.recordId
})))
```